# Routing in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app with the following models: Categories; Sub-Categories and Products. I have the models set up so that:
categories has_many sub_categories
sub_categories belongs_to categories 
sub_categories has_many products
products belongs_to sub_categories.

What I want is for each category to have individual sub_category(s), and each sub_category to have individual product(s). For example; I have a Category called "Foo", a sub_category called "Bar" and a product called "FooBar". I want "Foo" to only link to "Bar(s)" and "Bar" to only link to "FooBar(s)".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested resources to accomplish this.

```
resources :categories do
  resources :sub_categories do
    resources :products
  end
end
```

Then you set the category and sub_category object using the parameters `category_id` and `sub_category_id` passed to the products controller.

The [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) is awesome.